# Array_map for Objects?

Tags: javascript

I would like to filter an `object` that contains objects to get only those objects that contain an array with a specific value.

This is the object:

```
Object
-Object[0]
--Title
--Date
--Specs [Array]
---- [0] Name: "Power"
---- [0] Value: 5
---- [1] Name: "Weight"
---- [1] Value: 100
-Object[1]
--Title
--Date
--Specs [Array]
---- [0] Name: "Height"
---- [0] Value: 100
---- [1] Name: "Weight"
---- [1] Value: 100
```

As a result I want an object that only contains objects, where the `specs`-array contains an entry with the `Name` "Power".

I tried to solve this with array_map like this:

```
         return this.items.map((obj) => {
             let valObj = obj.specs.filter(function (elem) {
                 if (elem.Name == "Power") return elem.Value;
             });
             if (valObj.length > 0) {
                 return obj;
             }
         });
```

But unfortunately array_map works only on arrays, as the name already tells ;-)

So: Is there a good way to solve this problem?

Update:

Created a working code, but maybe not really elegant ;-)

```
itemsWithPower: function() {
                var items  = items;
                var list = [];

                var result = Object.keys(items).map(function(key) {
                    return items[key].Specs.filter(function(elem) {
                        if (elem.Name === "Power") list.push(items[key]);
                    });
                });             
                console.log(list);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Array.map` doesn't iterate over objects, you'd have to get an array first, for instance of the objects keys, something like

```
var items  = this.items;
var result = Object.keys(items).map(function(key) {
    return items[key].filter(function(obj) {
        return obj.Specs.Name === "Power";
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, just tried it and got back `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'key')`

Comment: @SPQRInc - then you don't have what you've shown us? Could be `this.items[key]` is an array, I edited the answer

Comment: Hi @adeneo, `this.items` is an object that contains other objects. Each object contains some information (Title, ID, and the `specs`-Array). I just created a screenshot from `console.log(this.items)`: http://imgur.com/a/NCr1y

I hope this helps?

Comment: Nope, that image doesn't help at all, it has none of the properties from your example code, which isn't very clear either? It should be rather straight forward to iterate, if you have an object, you could use `Object.keys(obj)` to get an array of keys you can use array methods on, and if you already have an array you can use array methods directly.

Comment: Hm, the problem, as I found out, is that `this.items` is undefined on `return this.items`.

Comment: @SPQRInc - oh that's right, the callback for Array.map creates a new `this`.

Comment: Hey, I got it working :-) Thanks a lot. I updated my initial post with my solution - this works as expected. Maybe there is a more elegant way? :-)